# Unidentified knob on Bogen 3066 head

Tags: tripod-heads, equipment-identification

I recently acquired a well-used Bogen 3066 head.  I am unable to identify the purpose of one of the knobs. It's a rather small, silver-colored knurled metal knob. It doesn't thread in very far, (not far enough to, say, tighten up or lock the elevation motion), nor is it removable as it does not thread all the way out.

The specific knob is ID'd in the pic as D2. Frustratingly, the pic's legend doesn't even have an entry for D2.

[image]

( pic lifted from [here](https://bogentripodparts.com/3066-8.html) )

Comment: It looks like `F1` is the tilt knob. Could it be that tightening `D2` provides drag so that you can tilt slowly and smoothly instead of having it be either tight/locked or loose/floppy?

Comment: This head has a detent that limits the tilt to 45 degrees. I don't see it listed on the parts diagram. Could this be the limit release?

Comment: I suppose it would provide a kind of ugly scraping drag if it threaded further in. I'm not ruling out that it's damaged (the head is quite well used).  But cranking the F1 knob in seems to provide a much more elegant "drag".